# Migration from FFMPEG 4.3.2 to 5.1.0 - Alternative to AVLockOp enum

Tags: ffmpeg, migration, deprecated

A lot of classes and enums that I use in FFMPEG 4.3.2 were removed from the version 5. The enum AVLockOp is one of them. I looked online for a AVLockOp alternative in the version 5.1.0 but I didn't find any. Is there an alternative to AVLockOp in FFMPEG 5.1.0?

I googled: "ffmpeg AVLockOp alternative", "ffmpeg AVLockOp deprecated", "ffmpeg 5.1 migration AVLockOp", etc...

I didn't find what I was looking for. So stackoverflow is my last hope.
I'm looking for someone who had the same issue or someone that knows an alternative to replace AVLockOp in FFMPEG 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's depreceted for:

> lavc: replace and deprecate the lock manager
>
> Use static mutexes instead of requiring a lock manager. The behavior
> should be roughly the same before and after this change for API users
> which did not set the lock manager at all (except that a minor memory
> leak disappears).

Removed here:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/e8fdb0db16c5ca8ad382b20874b4a454be6b79ae

Deprecated here:
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/a04c2c707de2ce850f79870e84ac9d7ec7aa9143